# A comparable sorter

Tags: java, swing, awt, actionlistener, comparable

I'm trying to get my code to compare the height of my randomly generated objects and sort them in ascending order. I'm currently having trouble understanding some basic concepts and as much as I read over the java docs I'm not finding an answer that works for me. I know that I don't have anything in my sorting listener, but I'm sort of at a loss as to where to go from here.

Edit: I've fixed portions of the code, but now there's a problem with it only redrawing a few of the bars and occasionally they are out of order.

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class Lab7 extends JPanel
{
    Random gen = new Random();
    boolean tick = true;
    private static bars[] bar = new bars[20];
    private static Integer[] height = new Integer[20], heightTemp = new Integer[1];
    private final int WIDTH = 500, HEIGHT = 300;
    private final int DELAY = 900;
    private int size = 15;
    int[] y = new int[20], yTemp = new int[1];
    int [] x = new int [20];
    Timer timer;
    public Lab7()
    {
        if(tick == true)
        {
            for(int count = 0; count < bar.length; count++)
            {
                height[count] = gen.nextInt(250) + 5;
                y[count] = (HEIGHT - height[count]);
                x[count] = (count * size +(count*5));
                bar[count] = new bars(x[count], y[count], size, height[count]);
            }
            tick = false;
        }
        timer = new Timer(DELAY, new SortingListener());
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
        setBackground(Color.white);
        timer.start();
    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics page)
    {
        super.paintComponent(page);
        for(int count = 0; count < bar.length; count++)
        {
            bar[count].draw(page);
        }
    }
    private class SortingListener implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
        {
            int min = 0;

            for(int count = 0; count < height.length; count++)
            {   
                for(int index = count + 1; index < height.length; index ++)
                {

                    if(height[count].compareTo(height[index]) > 0)
                    {
                        heightTemp[0] = height[count];
                        yTemp[0] = y[count];
                        height[count] = height[index];
                        y[count] = y[index];
                        height[index] = heightTemp[0];
                        y[index] = yTemp[0];
                    }
                    System.out.println(count + ":" + min);

                    if(index == 19 && height[count].compareTo(height[index]) != 0)
                    {
                        bar[count] = new bars(x[count], y[count], size, height[count]);
                        bar[index] = new bars(x[index], y[index], size, height[index]);
                    }

                }
                repaint();
            }
            timer.stop();
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Lab7");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(new Lab7());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Here's the Bars class as well.

```
public class bars{

Random gen =  new Random();
private int width = 20, height, x, y;
private int R = gen.nextInt(256);
private int G = gen.nextInt(256);
private int B = gen.nextInt(256);
public Color RandomColor;

//creates a rectangle
public bars(int x, int y, int width, int height)
{
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
}

public void draw(Graphics page)
{
    Color RandomColor = new Color(R, G, B);
    page.setColor(RandomColor);
    page.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
    Polygon p = new Polygon();
    page.setColor(RandomColor);
    page.fillPolygon(p);

}
public void setWidth(int width)
{this.width = width;}

public int getWidth()
{return width;}

public void setHeight(int height)
{this.height = height;}

public int getHeight()
{return height;}

public void setX(int x)
{this.x = x;}

public int getX()
{return x;}

public void setY(int y)
{this.y = y;}

public int getY()
{return y;}

public void setColor(Color RandomColor)
{this.RandomColor = RandomColor;}

public Color getColor()
{return RandomColor;}}
```

Comment: What is happening that is incorrect? Is the sort not working correctly? Share your observations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're doing a selection sort, the inner loop needs to start at the value of the outer loop. Change

```
for(int index = 0;
```

to

```
for(int index = count;
```

The error you're getting is that the list is unsorted right? It looks like only the first element of the "sorted" list will be in the correct spot.

Comment: That definitely was a problem, thanks for that, but i am still getting these errors.
//Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException//
 at Lab7$SortingListener.actionPerformed(Lab7.java:65)//
 at javax.swing.Timer.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)//
As well as a few other unknown source and native method errors.

Comment: Look at the list that you're sorting. You just do list = new ...[40] but you never initialize each of the 40 elements. They are all null. I don't know how you plan to initialize them, but you need to do it before the selection sort. You're crashing on the first use of the list. Probably on this line, list[scan].compareTo(list[min]).

(Lab7.java:65 <-- you're crashing on line 65. What is that line?

Comment: bah, thank you again. I went through and fixed up the code a bit. Aside from it not redrawing all the bars and only some of them being in order it's doing what I want it to do.

Comment: You can email me at my lastname.firstname at gmail and I can take a look at it more. Or just edit this post with newer code and I can take a look again. Since you're using random, could some of the bars have the same X/Y values causing them to be drawn on top of one another?

Comment: I just edited the post, it organizes, but every so often one or two are out of place.

Comment: I just figured it out, it was an unnecessary piece of my last if statement. && height[count].compareTo(height[index]) != 0.
Thank you for all the help :)